# Creating an array on HP P822 with non empty disks

Tags: raid, hp

I have several ProLiant ML310e servers with P822 RAID cards and have moved a RAID1 array of two disks between servers. Wanting to start fresh I deleted the RAID1 array and created a new one on the other server.  I noticed the array indicates no errors and "OK" status in iLO immediately.

I assumed it would need to rebuild the disks completely, as the contents would now be different?

Answer (score 0):

Typically deleting an existing RAID array means the data on the drives will be wiped as well, and even if the data remains on the drives, it will become inaccessible.

Are you using the RAID utility built into the RBSU/EFI or Smart Storage Administrator?

If the drives show as healthy and available, then you can go ahead create the required RAID array.